# VB.Net Changing Value of a property in one instance of a class, changes it in another instance

Tags: vb.net

I have the following (greatly simplified) VB.Net code:

```
Public Class Class1
   Public Property X Integer

   Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As [Object]) As Boolean
      If obj Is Nothing OrElse Not [GetType]().Equals(obj.GetType()) Then
         Return False
      End If
      Dim c As Class1 = CType(obj, Class1)
      Return X.Equals(c.X)
   End Function

End Class

Public Class Class2
   Public Property Y As Class1
      Get
         Return propY
      End Get
      Set(value As Class1)
         If value.X <> propY.X Then
         End If
      End Set
   End Property
   Private propY as New Class1
End Class

Sub Main()
   Dim C1 As New Class1
   C1.X = 1

   Dim C2 As New Class2
   C2.Y = C1

   Dim Cx as New Class1
   Cx.X = 2

   C2.Y = Cx
```

When the `C2.Y = Cx` statement executes, the test for inequality in the C2.Y property fails because propY.X is already set to 2 before the test executes.  Nothing is declared as "Shared".

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your example code doesn't actually make any sense. The setter of the `Class2.Y` property never actually sets the `propY` field so the `C2.Y = C1` line will have no effect at all. That code does not demonstrate the issue you're trying to show. Also, you ask us how to "fix" something without actually explaining what the expected outcome should be. You need to provide a much better explanation of the problem.

Comment: ...and where are the tests you're referring to? You're just making some assignments, there's no comparison here. Why do you have `[Object]` and `[GetType]` in brackets?